# Increase textarea width space evenly inside container, when over its width limit - css

Tags: html, css, pug

I'm trying to increase the size of this textarea evenly. But when I change it from 100% width to higher than that, it increases only to the right. I tried margin auto and display block but doesnt work.
Here is my css:

```
textarea[form="chform"] {

  width: 100%;
  height: 230px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: grey;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 4px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  resize:none;
}

.profile__form{
  padding: 15px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;

}
.profile_container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 120px auto 120px;
  /*background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(223,190,106,0.8), rgba(146,111,52,0.8), #f0f0f0, rgba(223,190,106,0.7));*/
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.075);
  text-align: center;
}
```

jade:

```
    extends layout
block content
 body(style='background-color:black')
    link(href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')
    div.right  
        if(user)
            a Welcome #{user.name}
            | &nbsp
            a(href='/main') Home
            | &nbsp
            a(href='/profile') Profile
            | &nbsp
            a(href='/logout') Logout
        else
            a(href='/main') Home
            | &nbsp
            a(href='/register') Register
            | &nbsp
            a(href='/login') Login 

    div.profile_container
        form.profile__form(role='form', action="/add-chapters",id="chform" method="post", style='max-width: 800px;')
            .profile__form-heading Add Chapter
            input.form-control(type='number', min="1" name="chapterNumber", id="inputChapterNumber" placeholder='Chapter Number')
            br
            input.form-control(type='text', name="chapterTitle", id="inputChapterTitle", placeholder='Title')


        textarea(name='chapterStory', cols='30', rows='5', form="chform", placeholder="Enter Story")
        br
        button.chform(type='submit') Save
```

HERE IS IMAGE of what I see so far after increasing width. I just want a bigger textarea and centered:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSBdL.jpg

**Edit: ok added parent css**

Comment: On the left there the parent element probably begin. Add finally HTML and relevant CSS. Ideally as a fiddle here.

Comment: ok i added css of parents

Comment: I asked you for creating a fiddle where we can see how it looks now. So add a HTML too, or better, create a working fiddle.

Comment: what is fiddle?

Comment: Forget. Add relevant HTML into question.

Comment: ok added rest of html

Answer (score 0):

IMAGE NOW FIXED:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbtiY.jpg

So I fixed it by increasing width of parent container the profile form and profile container. Then position relative, display block, and margin auto. Simple!

```
textarea[form="chform"] {

  width: 70%;
  height: 500px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: grey;
  font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 4px;
  resize:none;
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  margin-top: 10px;




}
```